# VSCode deploy source to org failed to run

Tags: vs-code, sfdx-plugin, sfdx-error

Starting today VSCode is giving me an error "SFDX: Deploy Source to Org failed to run".   This only happens with 1 org.  with every other org I do not have any issues.  I don't get any error it just says === Deploy Errors
15:27:22.623 ended SFDX: Deploy Source to Org

VSCode 1.55.2
sfdx-cli/7.81.0-7b953c80d1 win32-x64 node-v12.18.3

Comment: Have you tried to remove the connection and authorize the org again?

Comment: You could try logging into your target org, go to `Setup > Deployment Status`. If you can find additional errors there post them here. Also, try deploying sub-folders at a time and see if that works - f.e. only `classes` folder or `lwc` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a new project and re-authenticate the org to get it to work.